# Very Large Coordinates when Reading Shapefile using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, fiona

When using Python anad `fiona` package to read [a shapefile of Boston](http://www.mass.gov/anf/research-and-tech/it-serv-and-support/application-serv/office-of-geographic-information-massgis/datalayers/zipcodes.html), I am getting very large values in the tens of thousands. Why is this?

```
# Import Boston shapefile
shapefilename = 'ZIPCODES_NT_POLY'
shp = fiona.open(shapefilename + '.shp')
coords = shp.bounds
shp.close()
```

Then running `coords` gives the output

```
(33869.92130000144, 777617.2998000011, 330800.31099999696, 959741.1853)
```

Comment: An answer was given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900600/python-and-shapefile-very-large-coordinates-after-importing-shapefile  The file's original coordinate system was not considered

Comment: Cross-posted from http://stackoverflow.com/q/31900600

Answer (score 6):

On [the page you linked to](http://www.mass.gov/anf/research-and-tech/it-serv-and-support/application-serv/office-of-geographic-information-massgis/datalayers/zipcodes.html) (that describes the data you converted), it says:

> MassGIS also projected the data into the Massachusetts State Plane
>   Mainland coordinate system.

Consequently, values in the range that you are observing, are to be expected.

I am assuming that you were expecting latitude and longitude values *but this data has been projected*.

Comment: It is [EPSG:26986](http://epsg.io/26986) — NAD83 / Massachusetts Mainland